# Linux kernel module fixed execution time

Tags: linux-kernel, real-time

I'm developing kernel module where in probe function there is some chunk of code which consists of spi_writes/spi_reads... I need these chunk of code to have its execution time as fixed as possible (for example 200'000 ns straight)... What kernel hacks can I use to achieve these? (My kernel is 4.14.40 and it's not an RTLinux kernel).

Comment: Disabling IRQ and disabling preemption.

Comment: Can spinlock do both?

Comment: Yes. In any case I doubt that will help you, because with 99.9% probability `spi_read*()` and `spi_write*()` function calls involve IRQ handling along with sleeping contexts. You would really need to dirty hack kernel internals (at least SPI core framework) to make it working in poll mode and decrease, **drastically**, all possible time outs.